# Stop WordPress from auto-formatting certain codes

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a small question for you. How can I stop WordPress from changing the `&` symbol to `&#038;`? I found the solution to stop formatiing the code with pharagraphs by remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); but for this one I can't find it anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: IIRC removing the kses filters should do it. You should really know what you do, because that's all a bit fragile in wordpress, so you might have some security issues later on.

Comment: What's wrong with conversion from `&` to `&#038;`? These conversions circumvent possible character-encoding issues.

Comment: This conversion is necessary to produce valid HTML. (In short: all occurrences of `&` need to be escaped) Don't remove it lightly

Comment: Where does this happend? In the Post Editor, or when the code is outputted?

Comment: `&` is supposed to become `&#038;` in CMS scripts, because symbols being encoded solves all sorts of SQL, escaping, and other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I do most of my editing in the "HTML" tab view. Then I know the characters I enter will not be altered.

But there are times I want characters to be HTML-encoded. For example, I might mention some computer code in a post. I want the users to see those special characters, instead of the page interpreting my code example as HTML to be rendered. Then I go to the "Visual" tab to enter them.

In this way I have quick access to enter literal characters or to have them HTML-encoded.

If you really do want to prevent WordPress from ever encoding those characters, try some of these plugins. I haven't tried them, but they may help.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/preserve-code-formatting/

Comment: I open this question based on this answer. Perhaps you will find it interesting: [Why does the code editor not preserve the HTML characters?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/400964/64282)

Answer (score 0):

This caused me great headaches, so I created a shortcode to stop this behavior:

```
function do_not_filter_content_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    return wp_specialchars_decode($content);
}
add_shortcode( 'do_not_filter', 'do_not_filter_content_shortcode' );
```